# Why #Codable# not working in subclass which root class is confirmed to Codable protocol

Tags: swift4, codable

**[Xcode 9, Swift 4]**

I test following code:

Why the output is -1, not 1?

```
class A: Codable {

}

class A_a: A {
    var a: Int = -1
}

let json = """
{
"a": 1
}
"""
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!

let obj =  try? JSONDecoder().decode(A_a.self, from: jsonData)

obj?.a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol)

Comment: @the4kman this is not the duplicate of the question you mentioned.

Comment: Finally, I got the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553934/using-decodable-in-swift-4-with-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553934/using-decodable-in-swift-4-with-inheritance). @PGDev

Answer (score 0):

Codable is a `special` protocol. Its use is highly regulated. For example you cannot confirm to it in an extension. 
You can only rely on Types that confirm to Codable in their declaration.

I think, it is because how code-generation works.