# Ignoring superclass property while decoding subclass

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I'm trying to make inherited data model in order to parse it with `JSONDecoder`.

```
class FirstClass : Codable {
    let firstClassProperty: Int
    final let arrayOfInts: [Int]
}

class SecondClass : FirstClass {
    let secondClassProperty1: Int
    let secondClassProperty2: Int

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case secondClassProperty1, secondClassProperty2
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        secondClassProperty1 = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .secondClassProperty1)
        secondClassProperty2 = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .secondClassProperty2)

        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

I use this JSON for `FirstClass`:

```
{
    "firstClassProperty":  123,
    "arrayOfInts": [
        123
    ]
}
```

and this for `SecondClass`:

```
{
  "firstClassProperty": {},
  "secondClassProperty1": {},
  "secondClassProperty2": {}
}
```

How can I get rid of `arrayOfInts` in my subclass but let it be in superclass if keyword `final` doesn't work in this case?

Here's [Playground](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwYTgufDLtTMbnMwaFNGSVpveFU/view?usp=sharing). Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Why is `arrayOfInts` in your base class if it's not always needed?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there needs to be a hierarchy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack is to declare it as *optional*. For instance:

```
class FirstClas: Codable {
    let firstClassProperty: Int
    final let arrayOfInts: [Int]?
}
```

That would work around a missing `arrayOfInts` automatically.

**Manual solution**. Another solution is to implement the `Decodable` protocol yourself — as you did in `SecondClass` — and decode `arrayOfInts` using [`decodeIfPresent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2894339-decodeifpresent) (and use a default value otherwise).

---

**Superclass decoding**. By the way, the recommended way to forward the `Decoder` to the superclass is by using `superDecoder()` method:

```
...
let superDecoder = try container.superDecoder()
try super.init(from: superDecoder)
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I’m [struct junkie](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) myself but, without further info from good solitude3 here, I can’t really kill his classes point blank as you say, haha ;) He might need this capability inside a much larger app with a whole unknown set of design constraints...

Comment: @LeoDabus Not really true. A specific `superDecoder()` API, as used in my answer, signals to me that Apple clearly designed this to be used by *classes* as well. There might be some missing bits here and there, but the intention seems clear to me...

Comment: @LeoDabus ...and Apple actually provided a [complete, detailed example in WWDC 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605696/819340) :-)

Comment: I wouldn’t say so. This question is mainly focused on ignoring a superclass property (and not a full blown discussion about inheritance as the other question). OP really won’t be able to hack a solution by only looking at that other much larger question, IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
class FirstClass : Codable {
    let firstClassProperty: Int
    final let arrayOfInts: [Int]?
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstClassProperty = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .firstClassProperty)
        arrayOfInts = try container.decodeIfPresent([Int].self, forKey: .arrayOfInts)
    }
}
```

Comment: If the property is already marked as *optional*, I think the automatically generated code might be enough here — and, by the way, should be quite similar to what you have manually written ;)