# Encode Subclass with JSONEncoder

Tags: json, swift, inheritance, encoding

Im now sitting here on a, as I first thought, very simple problem. I want to **encode a object in Swift, which inheritance another Class**.

Here the Classes:

```
class NetworkMessage: Codable {
    var version:Int?
}

class AddPlayerRequest: NetworkMessage {

    var playerName: String?
    var playerHashedPw: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case playerName
        case playerHashedPw
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(playerName, forKey: .playerName)
        try container.encode(playerHashedPw, forKey: .playerHashedPw)

        try super.encode(to: encoder)
    }

}
```

I know there are millions of examples for that and I would say I am sure I did everything like in the examples, but it seems like I missed something, because when I try to encode a `AddPlayerRequest` like this:

```
let apr = AddPlayerRequest()
apr.playerName = "Test"
apr.playerHashedPw = "hynt87t7t76yt=="
apr.version = 1

do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let data = try encoder.encode(apr)
    let jsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The output is:

> {
>
> }

**EDIT: It seems that the same Code is working on another MAC. Anyone has an idea why it is possiblöe that the Code is running on one MAC, but not on another?**

Comment: Can you please describe what is netMsg2 ?

Comment: sorry I forgot to change it aswell, I thought it would be more clear for you if I name my variable apr ;)

Comment: I used your code and it works fine on my system :(

Comment: What!? :O How can it work on your system... I try to fix this problem for some days now and its really frustrating. Do you have an idea what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Yes I just run your code and I was able to generate json string. No idea what is wrong with the code which you had given in question.

Comment: And the String was not just "{}"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172537/discussion-between-julien-100000-and-sohan-vanani).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238196/inheritance-of-encodable-class