# Why #Codable# not working in below code?

Tags: json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I have below code to test `Codable` protocol and `JSONDecoder`.

```
import UIKit

class ClassA: Codable {
    var age: Int = 1
}

class ClassB: Codable {
    var ageInfo: ClassA?
    var name: String
}

let json4 = """
{
    "ageInfo": {},
    "name": "Jack"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let d = try JSONDecoder().decode(ClassB.self, from: json4)
} catch let err {
    print(err)
}
```

My question is, why **json4** can't be decode? or how I can decode **json4**?

Answer (score 1):

`age` in `ClassA` is declared non-optional so the key is required however in the JSON `ageInfo` is empty.

The error is

> No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "age")

Either declare `age` as optional

```
var age: Int?
```

or insert the key-value pair in the JSON

```
{
    "ageInfo": {"age" : 1},
    "name": "Jack"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ClassB has this:

```
var ageInfo: ClassA?
```

But that doesn’t help you with this JSON:

```
"ageInfo": {}
```

The problem is that `ageInfo` is *present* but it is also an *empty* dictionary. So there *is* a ClassA but it doesn't correspond to your definition of ClassA!

Change

```
class ClassA: Codable {
    var age: Int = 1
}
```

to

```
class ClassA: Codable {
    var age: Int? = 1
}
```

Comment: I see, so the default value of age is useless? I thought ```"ageInfo": {}``` is equal to ```"ageInfo": null```.

Comment: That would only be if null and empty-dictionary were the same. They are not. “No dictionary at all” is not the same as “an empty dictionary.”

Comment: Similarly in Swift itself, `nil` and `[:]` are two totally different things.

Comment: Similarly in real life. “My cup is empty” is not the same as “I have no cup.”