# Swift - JSONEncoder - encode date fields separately in a super class

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

I am very new to swift and I am trying to find a way to use the default encoding for a class that extends Codable and add separate data for certain fields.

For example, I have a class Contact which extends Codable, with a lot of 
fields and I want to encode dates differently from default (By default JSONEcoder puts dates as timestamps, but I want to use a different format)
For simplicity, let's say my class is:

```
class Contact:Codable {
    var name: String?
    var id: String?
    var birthdate: Date?
}
```

For custom encoding I used this link: [Using Decodable in Swift 4 with Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553934/using-decodable-in-swift-4-with-inheritance)

The issue is that I do not want to encode each field separately because the default encode does this. I just want to add only certain values to the encoded json.

I also found this link about dynamic keys but I don't know how to use it exactly: https://gist.github.com/samwize/a82f29a1fb34091cd61fc06934568f82

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "encode date differently"?

Comment: @Sweeper: By default, JSONEcoder serializes dates as timestamps, but I want to use a different format

Comment: @vadian: what do you mean by synthesized en-/decoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to encode dates differently, you can set the `dateEncodingStrategy` of the `JSONEncoder` to one of the preset values.

You might want to set it to `.custom` or `formatted` if your way of encoding is very special.

```
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .custom({
    date, encoder in
    ...
})
// or
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "some format"
encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```