# Make class conforming to Codable by default in Swift

Tags: json, swift, inheritance, codable

Such feature of Swift as `Codable` (`Decodable`&`Encodable`) protocol is very useful.
But I found such issue:
Let we have class Parent conforming to `Codable`:

```
class Parent: Codable {
    var name: String
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
}
```

Ok, that class is conforming to Codable protocol "from the box", you don't need write any initializers, it's ready to be initialized from JSON like that:

```
{ "name": "John", "email": "johndoe@yahoo.com", "password": <null>}
```

But let's say we need other class, Child inherits from Parent and be conforming to Codable:

```
class Child: Parent {
   var token: String
   var date: Date?
}
```

so class Child must be conforming to Codable by conformance to Parent,
BUT properties of class Child won't be initialized from JSON properly.
Decision I found is write all Codable stuff for class Child by myself, like:

```
class Child: Parent {
    var token: String
    var date : Date?

    enum ChildKeys: CodingKey {
        case token, date
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try super.init(from: decoder)
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ChildKeys.self)
        self.token = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
        self.date = try container.decodeIfPresent(Date.self, forKey: .date)
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ChildKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.token, forKey: .token)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(self.date, forKey: .date)
    }
}
```

But I feel it can't be right, did I missed something? How to make class Child conforming to Codable properly without writing all that stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Decodable in Swift 4 with Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553934/using-decodable-in-swift-4-with-inheritance)

Comment: Agreed, my bad didn't checked for previous questions

Comment: Same problem everywhere you look. In .Net, they use explicit uninherited attributes to describe serialization on a type...so that you're not lulled into thinking there's any way to inherit serializability. Swift's approach strikes me as an anti-pattern...leaving a consumer to expect that a subtype of a conforming type to conform at birth. Sure it technically does...but as you have identified, it breaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a good blog post which includes an answer to your question: [source](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/)

**Scroll down to inheritance and you'll see the following:**

Assuming we have the following classes:

```
class Person : Codable {
    var name: String?
}

class Employee : Person {
    var employeeID: String?
}
```

We get the Codable conformance by inheriting from the Person class, but what happens if we try to encode an instance of Employee?

```
let employee = Employee()
employee.employeeID = "emp123"
employee.name = "Joe"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let data = try! encoder.encode(employee)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

{
  "name" : "Joe"
}
```

This is not the expected result, so we have to add a custom implementation like this:

```
class Person : Codable {
    var name: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Same story for the subclass:

```
class Employee : Person {
    var employeeID: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case employeeID = "emp_id"
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(employeeID, forKey: .employeeID)
    }
}
```

The result would be:

```
{
  "emp_id" : "emp123"
}
```

Which again is not the expected result, so here we are using **inheritance** by calling **super**.

```
// Employee.swift
    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(employeeID, forKey: .employeeID)
    }
```

Which finally gives us what we really wanted from the beginning:

```
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "emp_id": "emp123"
}
```

If you're not happy with the flattened result, there's a tip on how to avoid that too.

All the credits to the guy who wrote the blog post and my thanks.
Hope it helps you as well, cheers!