# Inheriting codable class raises error "required' initializer"

Tags: swift, inheritance, codable

I inherited Codable class like below.

```
class Vehicle: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    let type: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, type: String) {
        self.type = type
        super.init(id: id, name: name)
    }
}
```

And it shows error

```
'required' initializer 'init(from:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Vehicle'
```

What is a proper way to inherit codable class?

Answer (score 1):

If you allow Xcode to fix the issue, it adds this method to the subclass:

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: So I leave this fatal error like we do when creating custom init for UIView subclasses and everything works fine?

Comment: Have a look here for how to implement it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605696/14506724)