# Decoding a Codable with class type returned from a function actually returns an item with its superclass as type

Tags: swift, subclass, codable, downcast

I wrote a custom decoder for a json response where I have a "content" field that can be decoded to various different classes, all of them inheriting from the same ContentItem superclass. I also have a function that returns a class type, which I use in my decoder (I know that there may be different ways to do this, but that's not the problem):

```
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        ...
        guard let type = type, let contentItemType = getItemClass(from: type) else { return }
        content = try container.decode(contentItemType, forKey: .content)
    }

    func getItemClass(from type: ProductContentType) -> ContentItem.Type? {...}
```

ProductContentType is a String enum. The getItemClass function returns the correct class, I've checked while debugging:

```
    getItemClass(from: .type1) === Item1Class.self   //<-- this returns true
```

The problem is the following:

```
    guard let type = type, let contentItemType = getItemClass(from: type) else { return }
    content = try container.decode(contentItemType, forKey: .content)
    // ^ In this case content is kind of class ContentItem
    let downcastContent = content as? Item1Class // <- downcastContent is nil

    content = try container.decode(Item1Class.self, forKey: .content)
    // ^ In this case content is kind of class Item1Class
    let downcastContent = content as? Item1Class // this works
```

Downcasting with the content in the first case returns nil, but it doesn't make sense to me. Also I've noticed that when decoding the item the init(from: Decoder) in the subclass is never called.
Is it supposed to be this way? I was expecting both decode to return a content with class Item1Class. Am I missing something in the decode process in the first case?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it supposed to be this way?

Yes. Note that you don't know exactly what the decoded type is - `getItemClass` could have returned `Item1Class.self`, or `Item2Class.self`, or `Item3Class.self`, and so on. But you do know that whatever it returns, it is a subclass of `ContentItem`, so at least, you can assign it to a variable of type `ContentItem`, so `content` could only be of type `ContentItem.Type`.

More accurately, `getItemClass` returns `ContentItem.Type`, which becomes the inferred type of `contentItemType`, and when you passed it to the `decode` method, the generic parameter `T` is inferred to be `ContentItem`. The return type of `decode` is also `T`, so `content` has the type `ContentItem`.

However, just like how even though `contentItemType` has the type `ContentItem.Type`, its value is actually a `Item1Class.self`, even though `content` has the type `ContentItem`, it actually has a reference to a `Item1Class` instance. You can show this by showing that casting succeeds:

```
let item1 = content as! Item1Class // this succeeds
```

or you can check the runtime type of `content` directly:

```
type(of: content) == Item1Class.self / true
```

`JSONDecoder` *will* actually look at the `contentItemType` that you passed to it. That parameter is not just used to infer `T`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
class Foo : Decodable {
    let a: String
}

class Bar: Foo {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case b
    }
    
    let b: String
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        b = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .b)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

let json = """
{"a": "Foo", "b": "Bar"}
""".data(using: .utf8)

func getItemClass() -> Foo.Type {
    Bar.self
}

let type = getItemClass()
let fooButItsActuallyBar = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: json!)
let bar = fooButItsActuallyBar as! Bar // this succeeds
print(bar.a, bar.b)
```

Note that in the above example, the subclass `Bar` has overridden the required initialiser to implement custom decoding, because the auto-generated implementation isn't generated for subclasses ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553934/using-decodable-in-swift-4-with-inheritance)). If you didn't override it, you will see the subclass's properties uninitialised. That could be another reason why you think `decode` decodes an instance of `ContentItem`.

Comment: The fact is, downcasting doesn't return the correct class in my code. I've tried your code, and it works, but with mine downcasting to Item1Class returns nil. From what I've seen the init(from: Decoder) in the subclasses isn't called - at all. I've updated the question with these infos

Comment: @Kappei Well then you need to show a [mcve].